# Counting the number of highlighted words in richtextbox using c#

Tags: c#

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string[] show = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' '); 
    string type = textBox1.Text; 
    for (int i = 0; i < show.Length; i++)
    {
        int num = 0; 
        if (show[i] == textBox1.Text)
            num++;
    } 
    Label1.Text = num.ToString();   
}
```

Im using `richTextBox1` to display the file and the `textBox1` to search for a word and highlight it. I want to display how many words are highlighted in the label box but it always shows zero. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should move `int num = 0;` out of your loop, since in each iteration it will be set to 0;

Comment: I did it sir but still the output is zero. I put it after string type.

Comment: @BlankOP In that case your strings are not exactly the same (or equal). Take into account casing, leading/trailing whitespaces, and content as well

Comment: What to do about it sir? Im only a beginner.

Comment: @darjanbogdan what to do about it sir? Im only a beginner.

Comment: @BlankOP In order to see clearly what's going on, you should use debugger, please find more information about it on following link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: Thankyou very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the new line character condition.

In my example, I remove Chr(13) and replace Chr(10) with a space, so it behaves the same way as a space character:

```
        string[] show = richTextBox1.Text.Replace(Convert.ToChar(13).ToString(), " ").Replace(Convert.ToChar(10).ToString(), " ").Split(' ');
        string type = textBox1.Text;
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < show.Length; i++)
        {

            if (show[i].Trim() == textBox1.Text)
                num++;
        }
        textBox1.Text = num.ToString();
```

Comment: Thankyou ive figured it out that im lacking with replace.

Comment: How would i detect sql only from mysql? The program only detect sql but the sql in mysql cant be detected.

Comment: this question wasnt about sql?

Comment: No sir. The text file i create have a sentence about sql.

Comment: thats a VERY different question that what was asked...you asked about searching for spaces...a mysql syntax parser is way out of the bounds of the scope of the question...you need to open a separate question for that in my opinion

Comment: sir if there is a word like has and I only search for as it highlights as but if I would like to count the occurrence of the word as it shows me 0 result. it only have a problem when the search word is part of a word and not the whole word.